# Override derived member in a class

Tags: c#, events

When I override an event from a parent class, for example the OnLoad() method in System.Web.UI.Page, why is "base.OnLoad(e)" still called, but even when I remove the call to the overridden method in the base class, the Load event is still fired?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying that when you remove `base.OnLoad(e)` from your `OnLoad` method, it doesn't fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to base.OnLoad(e) ensures that everything in the base implementation of the method gets called in addition to your code overriding that method (rather than only the code in your overriden method being executed).

In either case, it should have no bearing on the event being successfully fired or not.

Comment: Yeah, raising the event is a different situation from handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code `protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)` is not overriding an event, because `OnLoad` is not an event. It is overriding a method defined on `System.Web.UI.Control`, from which `System.Web.UI.Page` inherits, which [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onload.aspx) says raises the `Load` event.

If your implementation of `OnLoad` calls `base.OnLoad(e)`, you should find that the `Load` event is raised.

If your implementation of `OnLoad` does NOT call `base.OnLoad`, you should find that the `Load` event is NOT raised.

You almost certainly want to make sure you are calling `base.OnLoad`.